# Selling product and coupon in wordpress website, is there any direction / tutorial / plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Background:
I know how to develop a website using php and html but I am a newer in wordpress and I bought a wordpress theme for my blogger which only show article for visitors view and no membership system in there. Now, I want to add a big new function but don't know should I buy a plugin or develop myself, so in here I want to get a direction / tutorial / plugin.

Big new function:
1. membership can using fb login or email
2. selling product, after payment send email to user (user can choose login / anonymous to buy it, if login which will using their information to buy)
3. selling product, after payment send coupon to user (user can choose login / anonymous to buy it, if login which will using their information to buy and coupon code will automatically generate which can be unique / same code for one product)
4. user can use unique coupon code (qrcode / barcode) to go to a shop to get a service / product
5. the shop shopkeeper will scan the code using my website cms
6. shopkeeper / admin can view the cms which contain that shop payment and how many people have already use the coupon
7. free coupon for user which can using it in physical store

Thanks for help!!!!

Comment: push push push push

Comment: push push push push

Comment: push push push push